# action delegate with zero parameters

Tags: c#, delegates, action

I see this line in many online examples of using the Action delegate:

```
public event Action MyEvent;
```

But when I try it in my own code, I get this error

> Using the generic type
>   'System.Action' requires '1' type
>   arguments

The documentation certainly describes a form of Action without any type parameter. What am I missing?

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but you shouldn't use an Action for an event. Use either EventHandler or EventHandler<T> as the delegate for events.

Comment: @GregBeech, thanks for the tip, but what is the reason not to use Action here?

Comment: @I.J.Kennedy This answer is pretty awesome http://stackoverflow.com/a/803320/1608072

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure your application is referencing `System.Core`.

Edit - also make sure you are targeting .NET 3.5 as the System.Core.dll is part of that version.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not have a System.Core reference.
Even knowing the answer, I still could not find it in the docs.

Answer (score 39):

Expanding on Andrews answer.

It's perfectly legal to use Action in a non-3.5 scenario.  Simply define it yourself.

```
public delegate void Action();
```

Comment: Unless you are passing it to someone elses library, that is using System.Core's Action...

Comment: @Simon, in that case you must already be using 3.5 (directly or indirectly) so it's not an issue.