# How to raise event using addHandler

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-3.0, events, handler

I am comfortable with Vb.Net events and handlers.
Can anybody will help me with how to create event handlers in c#, and raise events.

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: I think he just wants to know how to add event handlers and raise events in C#, and he already knows how to do it in VB.

Comment: Mitesh, I edited your question quite a lot. I was just trying to improve the English. If I've misunderstood what you were asking, I'm sorry - please just change it back.

Answer (score 13):

Developers who know only C#, or only VB.Net, may not know that this is one of the larger differences between VB.NET and C#.

I will [shamelesssly copy](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2008/12/01/What-C-Devs-Should-Know-About-VB.aspx?Page=2) this nice explanation of VB events: VB uses a declarative syntax for attaching events. The [Handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx) clause appears on the code that will handle the event. When appropriate, multiple methods can handle the same event, and multiple events can be handled by the same method. Use of the Handles clause relies on the [WithEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aty3352y.aspx) modifier appearing on the declaration of the underlying variable such as a button. You can also attach property handlers using the [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) keyword, and remove them with RemoveHandler. For example

```
Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox   

Private Sub TextBox1_Leave(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Leave
  'Do Stuff '
End Sub
```

In C# you can't use the declarative syntax. You use += which is overloaded to act like the VB.Net AddHandler. Here's an example shamelessly stolen from [tster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488573/how-to-raise-event-using-addhandler/1488623#1488623):

```
public MyClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Leave += new EventHandler(testBox1_Leave);
}

void testBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In C# 2 and up you add event handlers like this:

```
yourObject.Event += someMethodGroup;
```

Where the signature of `someMethodGroup` matches the delegate signature of `yourObject.Event`.

In C# 1 you need to explicitly create an event handler like this:

```
yourObject.Event += new EventHandler(someMethodGroup);
```

and now the signatures of the method group, event, and `EventHandler` must match.

Answer (score 3):

```
    public MyClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.LostFocus += new EventHandler(testBox1_LostFocus);
    }

    void testBox1_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these.

[Understanding events and event handlers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ddutta/EventHandlingInNetUsingCS11092005052726AM/EventHandlingInNetUsingCS.aspx

http://www.csharphelp.com/archives2/archive408.html