# C# <===> VB.Net Keywords Mapping

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am well versed with coding in C# but now I have to code in VB.Net. So for learning sake is there any article/list out there that can tell me that like

```
  C#          |       VB.Net
```

---

```
abstract      |     MustInherit
 sealed       |    NotInheritable
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a good idea, as there are some differences (in particular with respect to events and modules). Why don't you want to browse through a textbook on VB.Net and mark the important points yourself?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9978/Complete-Comparison-for-VB-NET-and-C

Comment: @Habib: How about that as an answer?

Comment: Have a look at some existing questions. [What are the differences between C# and VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523722/what-are-the-differences-between-c-net-and-visual-basic-net). Also advice on learning VB.Net for C# programmers. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684821/whats-the-best-way-for-a-c-sharp-developer-to-learn-vb) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790772/converting-myself-from-c-sharp-to-vb-net)

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, just noticed this article in one of the answers :), I believe the comment has served the purpose :)

Comment: ... and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337253/converting-c-sharp-knowledge-to-vb-net-any-potential-problems)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html --> Good comparison chart

Comment: +1 I used to use that all the time when I had to support a VB.NET app that had been automatically ported from VB.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one from 2005, but very well written:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9978/Complete-Comparison-for-VB-NET-and-C

Here is another:
http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

I suggest two alternatives:

- Use a decompiler which allows you to choose the target language like [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).
- There are code translators like [this one](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/).

In any case you will have to pick a good book about VB.NET to learn the subtile differences between both languages.