# If the autoreset is set to false, will my timer be disposed automatically?

Tags: c#, timer, dispose

I launch a timer only one time in my application:

```
CustomTimer timer = new CustomTimer(mod);
timer.Interval = interval.TotalMilliseconds;
timer.AutoReset = false;
timer.Start();
```

So the AutoReset is set to false. At the end of the timer, will the dispose method be called automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it will not. [AutoReset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.autoreset.aspx) will simply state whether the Elapsed event should be triggered each time the interval elapses, or only the first time.

You can e.g. hook up an event handler to the [Tick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx) and do whatever disposing you need to.

Comment: thank your for your answer. but i'm not very good with the event handler. could give me an example of what you are talking about : "hook up an event handler to the Tick event" and where to put the disposing ? thx

Comment: You can see an example in the Tick event link in my answer. Basically: Objects events can be subscribed to by adding an event handler. In your case the Timer class has a Tick event. You can hook up an event handler to this by saying myTimer.Tick += MyHandler; See the link, and google for "C# events" etc, and I'll sure you'll figure this out. I don't know what you actually want to dispose? But if you're holding some resources that you don't need any more you can dispose them in your event handler.

Comment: This question should tell you everything you need about events and event handling in c#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c

Answer (score 1):

No, The timer just will not Reset back to zero. The resources used for the timer wil still be used because the reference to the object  still exists.