# defining event handler for Tick event of DispatcherTimer in windows 8 app

Tags: windows-8

I am developing an application in windows 8 Visual studio 11, and I want to define an event handler for a DispatcherTimer instance as below:

```
public sealed partial class BlankPage : Page
    {

        int timecounter = 10;
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        public BlankPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(HandleTick);
        }

        private void HandleTick(object s,EventArgs e)
        {

            timecounter--;
            if (timecounter ==0)
            {
                //disable all buttons here
            }
        }
        .....
}
```

But I get the following Error :

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler<object>'
```

I am a novice developer to widows 8 apps.

Would you please help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

almost had it :) You don't need to instantiate a new eventhandler object, you only need to point to the method that handles the event. Hence, an eventhandler.

```
        int timecounter = 10;
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public BlankPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    }

    protected void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        timecounter--;
        if (timecounter == 0)
        {
            //disable all buttons here
        }
    }
```

Try to read up on delegates to understand events [Understanding events and event handlers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp)

Comment: But we dont have this problem in Windows Applications ? Do we ?

Comment: A delegate and an eventhandler is the same across the platform. It's not a "problem", it's how it Works :)

Comment: By problem I meant 'System.EventHandler<object>' and I dont mean that is a bug

Comment: this is the alternate solution. I want to know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is expecting HandleTick to have two Object params. Not an object param and an EventArg param.

```
private void HandleTick(object s, object e)
```

NOT

```
private void HandleTick(object s,EventArgs e)
```

This is a change that took place for Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

WinRT makes use of Generics more than the standard .NET Runtime. DispatcherTimer.Tick as [defined in WinRT is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.tick.aspx):

```
public event EventHandler<object> Tick
```

While the [WPF DispatcherTimer.Tick is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.tick.aspx)
    public event EventHandler Tick

Also note that you don't have to use the standard named method to create an Event Handler. You can use a lambda to do it in place:

```
int timecounter = 10;
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
public BlankPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    timer.Tick += (s,o)=>
    {
       timecounter--;
       if (timecounter == 0)
       {
           //disable all buttons here
       }
    };
}
```