# Understanding delegates and Events in C# using a specific example

Tags: c#, events, delegates

So I'm at the point of understanding events and delegates.

I overally understand the usage of delegates.
The only thing that concerns me about delegates is whether a delegate can be configured to work with functions that are not related to events in any way... **if yes, how do I write the logic for a delegate-defined function?** (I guess such function doesn't really have much of a point to it, but it's good to know.)

As for events... I'm having a hard time understanding it. I get the idea that an event is a function that gets executed when something happens in the code.
However, I don't get the process of creating an event. Partially.

For this question I'll use an answer by **Gary Willoughby**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/803528/1104766 
It was posted on a question from which I tried to understand this whole subject.

What I didn't get in the example above:
`MyObject.OnMaximum += new MyEventHandler(MaximumReached);`
First, **how can you create an instance of a delegate, and pass it only 1 variable when it requires 2?** There must be something I'm missing...
The second thing about this line is that the `new ...()` instance is being **added** to the `OnMaximum` function that resides in `MyObject` which is an instance of `MyClass` - **what exactly is `OnMaximum` if such thing can be done?** It was never really defined too!

```
      if(OnMaximum != null) {
        OnMaximum(this, new MyEventArgs("You've entered " +
          value.ToString() +
          ", but the maximum is " +
          Maximum.ToString()));
      }
```

As for this part, `OnMaximum` is called but it's logic was never really defined anywhere in the code, so what could be the outcome? Obviously I'd guess it'd be the text "You've entered............." but my question is to be more specific, **what really happens with the values the function/event receives?**

I marked all of my questions in **BOLD** for clarity.

P.S, I know this question **generally** has been posted a few times.
Please note that this specific question refers to an answer written by another member and the questions asked here are specific to this example. That's why such answers can't really be found in google.
For the record though, I did search before I posted, and I did try to understand, but I guess examples are the best way for me to understand something especially when my knowledge of the English CS vocabulary is lacking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you may be suffering from an overdose of syntactic sugar!

You see, all an event is, is a delegate.  Actually, to be honest, it's a collection of delegates that can possibly be `null`.

Let's take an example:

```
public class Alarm
{
    public delegate void AlarmEvent();

    // my secret stuff

    // raise it!
    public void Ring()
    {
        if(OnAlert != null)
           OnAlert();
    }

    public event AlarmEvent OnAlert;
}
```

All the event keyword gives us here, is the ability to add and remove listeners to that event...

```
Alarm a = new Alarm();
a.OnAlert += myevent;
a.OnAlert += myotherevent;
```

A delegate on the other hand, whilst working exactly like we have just described, works more analogously as a function pointer.  Imagine an abstract renderer, I could make the class as such:

```
public abstract class Renderer
{
    protected abstract void RenderImpl();
}
```

This means, I am bound to deriving from that render.  But what if that renderer took a delegate?

```
public abstract class Renderer
{
    public delegate void RenderDelegate();

    public Renderer(RenderDelegate) { /* ... */ }
}
```

We are now separating out composition.

What am I getting at?  Is either better or not?  In the case of events, I am allowing the public to become observers of my class.  They can react.  In the second case, I define a user-supplied delegate to perform a niche function, whilst I retain the majority of control.

Delegates and events are mostly the same thing - but it is the design choices we make that ascertains which one is appropriate.

To address your other points, you bring up a great example of events versus delegates.  If we were to change the alarm class above, to allow the delegate to return `true` or `false`, then what happens?

We'd get several observers returning true, but who is right and how to we check them?

Down the single delegate route, however...  "Render successful" or "Render failed".  Changing this single delegate is not so much of an issue.  We can predictably test whether our renderer did the job:

```
if(!delegate_->Invoke())
    fallBackCode();
```

We can't really do that with events.  Well, not predictably.

To put it more simply, events are there when you want to broadcast something and let someone else do something on receipt of that event.  The bomb went off...  Run, hide, call the National Guard, turn off the oven, or duck and cover.

Delegates allow you to change your functionality without changing your model (delegates follow a signature!).  Great example of a delegate, is when you call `List<T>.Sort`.  That's a delegate.  It has a signature.

But you can also use them for more advanced things, such as altering a `Renderer` class without resorting to interfaces, and being able to supply a user-defined "snippet".  I guess the easiest analogy here would be owner-drawn controls in Win32.  No need to override the whole class, no need to provide an interface and write a lot of code.  Just change the bit that renders the item in the combo box.  Delegates are great examples of how you might achieve that.

Comment: So your `myevent` and `myotherevent` equal the `MaximumReached` function/listener declared in the question I linked to? Does that mean that when an event is called like `someHandler(int num)` fires all of it's listeners AND passes them the available variables? That must also mean that all of the listeners assigned to a handler receive/return the same type/amount of variables, right? makes sense - Thanks! However, I still don't quite understand your last example... It could really help me if you could provide an example of both usages with/without the delegate (even a theoretical way would do).

Comment: @xTCx, I've expanded my answer a little.  Hope it helps :)

Comment: The whole `invoke()` part kinda confused me (I didn't learn the renderer class yet so that might be the problem) BUT, the rest made it clear to me: Events basically alert listeners about something, the listeners then react according to the delegate the sets some kind of restrictions to the listener's behavior, am I right?... Delegates allow functions to share similar signature while allowing different logic. A good example for it would be a Person. All persons are persons, but they all **look** different... If that makes sense.

Comment: @xTCx, close enough!  Events "alert".  And you wouldn't necessarily be able to change the outcome of it (though you might, through a supplied object), but given the global nature it's not advised.  A delegate is more succinct and purposeful. :)

Comment: The only one line I didn't get is `public Renderer(RenderDelegate)` - a delegate is being received and not an appearance of it as a function as seen in example 1 in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx . Must be because of the fact that this is an abstract class, but I still have no idea what's the behavior in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorials at MSDN will answer all your questions:

Delegates: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(v=vs.71).aspx

Events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Problem is the information there just makes it even more confusing to me. That's why I chose to focus on one specific example and analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Parent p = new Parent();
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    public delegate void DelegateName(string data);

    class Child
    {
        public event DelegateName delegateName;

        public void call()
        {
            delegateName("Narottam");
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////

    class Parent
    {
        public Parent()
        {
            Child c = new Child();
            c.delegateName += new DelegateName(print);
            //or like this
            //c.delegateName += print;
            c.call();
        }

        public void print(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("yes we got the name : " + name);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Come on Guys! All of you successfully complicated the DELEGATES :)!

I will try to leave a hint here : i understood delegates once I realized jquery ajax calls in Javascript. for ex: ajax.send(url, data, successcallback, failcallback) is the signature of the function. as you know, it sends data to the server URL, as a response, It might be 200OK or some other error. In case of any such event(success/fail), you want to execute a function. So, this acts like a placeholder of a function, to be able to mention in either success or failure.
That placeholder may not be very generic - it might accept a set of parameters and may/may not return value. That declaration of such Placeholder, if done in C# IS CALLED DELEGATE! As javascript functions not strict with number of arguments, you would just see them as GENERIC placeholders...but C# has some STRICT declarations... that boils down to DELEGATE declarations!!

Hope it helps!

Comment: What do you mean by GENERIC placeholders.I lost there

Comment: I mean, GENERIC Placeholder  as function placeholder; you can define any function, say ExtFunct1() outside of this page/component where ajax.send is defined, when actual ajax.send called, put the name of the function "ExtFunct1" in success or fail callback parameter place[placeholder], thats get called at runtime.