# Please explain the meaning of the following C# code

Tags: c#, winforms

What does the event "VisibleChanged" mean?

For example in this code of this line:

```
slidePane.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(slidePane_VisibleChanged);
```

Comment: please add more code, for example let us know the type of the "slidePane" variable, let us know the context (in wchich method) and let us know on which platform (Silverlight, WinForms, WPF,...)

Comment: You would benefit from an introductory C# book.

Answer (score 5):

Here "VisibleChanged" is an event, "slidePane_VisibleChanged" is the event handler. You are to attach the event handler to that event. So when the event fires, the event handler will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying it does this:
When the visibility of the slideplane is changed, invoke the event handler slidePane_VisibleChanged.

See also a more detailed explanation of event handling on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/803320/103139

and on MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: thats not 100% correct because it add the method to the handler

Comment: You are right. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is an `Event Handler` attachment. You are attaching an event handler to your `slidePane's` `VisibleChanged` event. You have a method named `slidePane_VisibleChanged` that matches the signature of your `EventHandler`. When your `VisibleChanged` event triggered your `slidePane_VisibleChanged` method will be executed.

Also this line can be written like this:

```
slidePane.VisibleChanged += slidePane_VisibleChanged;
```

That is the short notation of attaching an event handler. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more details.