# Calling a method of another class with no relationship

Tags: c#, class, methods

I'm learning to code, but there are things that i still don't know.
As it is difficult to me explain what I want, here I show the code.

```
public class classOne {

    classTwo object = new ClassTwo();

    (...)

    public void WhenClassTwoHasEnded {
        (...)
    }
}

public class classTwo {

    public classTwo () {(...)}

    public classTwoAsyncStuff {
        (...)
        notifyEnd();
    }

    public void notifyEnd() {
        //How I can call WhenClassTwoHasEnded from here?
    }
}
```

Usually I always find the answer to my questions on Stack Overflow, but I've been searching for a while and have not found anything, because of my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do that in many different ways. Here are some:

> 1) Let ClassOne run the method of its ClassTwo instead of calling it directly. So ClassOne has an (async if you want) method in which it calls `await classTwo.classTwoAsyncStuff()` and then `this.WhenClassTwoHasEnded()`
>
> 2) You could add [event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/803320/929276)
>
> 3) You could also send the [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Func](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the method and let it run it when it's done.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you very much for your answer. I hope to continue learning and not have to ask much more. I am very grateful for your response.

Comment: And you're welcome. But you shouldn't be afraid of asking for help if you're stuck and can't find the answer. It'll save you a lot of time and you might learn some new and interesting things :)