# Open TK difference onRenderFrame and onUpdateFrame?

Tags: opengl, methods, overriding, opentk, subscribe

I am currently programming a Jump n' Run game in C# using OpenTK Framework and OpenGL.

Open TK provides preset functions like `GameWindow.Run();` or `GameWindow.onUpdateFrame();` `onRenderFrame();`

As far as i thought through it, all actions that draw OpenGL elements or primitives should belong into onRenderFrame, whereas game events like player movement should be performed in onUpdateFrame, so these actions can be calculated in advance before rendering a new frame.

**Am I right?** Would it make a difference to perform all actions in the onRenderFrame method? OpenTK suggests not to override these methods and subscribing to their Events (onRenderFrameEvent) instead.

[http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/class_open_t_k_1_1_game_window.html#abc3e3a8c21a36d226c9d899f094152a4]](http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/class_open_t_k_1_1_game_window.html#abc3e3a8c21a36d226c9d899f094152a4%5d)

What is **subscribing** and how would i subscribe to an **event** instead of overriding a method?

```
protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnUpdateFrame(e);

    this.gameObjects.moveObjects();

    this.player.Move();
    if (this.player.jumpstate == true) this.player.Jump();
}

protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnRenderFrame(e);

    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

    Matrix4 modelview = Matrix4.LookAt(Vector3.Zero, Vector3.UnitZ, Vector3.UnitY);
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
    GL.LoadMatrix(ref modelview);

    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.Translate(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.5f);

    this.gameObjects.drawObjects();
    this.player.Draw();

    SwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: I think that `updateFrame` is so you can update your geometry & matrices, while `renderFrame` is to actually draw everything,

Comment: `renderFrame` is the main loop, processed as often as possible (if vsync disabled) while updateFrame is triggered at fixed interval defined with a parameter in your context creation (usualy 30 or 60 times/second).

Comment: Triggering rendering as fast as possible is for overall performance appreciation (as far as we know) because of human eyes frame rate perception limit. if your update function doesn't slow the process under that limit, you may trigger frame computations wherever you want.

Answer (score 12):

It's pretty much as the comments said: update your world in the `UpdateFrame` event and render it in `RenderFrame`.

This makes sense when you realize that your game will run on wildly different hardware. Some computers might only be able to render your game at 15fps. Others will achieve a solid 60fps. And players with 120Hz monitors will want your game to run at 120fps in order to enjoy the full potential of their systems.

In all those cases, you want your game logic to *run at the same speed* and give *identical results*.

The simplest way to achieve this is by setting a fixed `UpdateFrame` rate in `GameWindow.Run()`:

```
using (var game = new GameWindow())
{
     game.VSync = VSyncMode.Adaptive;
     game.Run(60.0, 0.0);
}
```

This code snippet instructs OpenTK to raise 60 `UpdateFrame` events per second and as many `RenderFrame` events as the system can handle, up to the refresh rate of the monitor. When running on a slower system, OpenTK will drop `RenderFrame` events in order to ensure a solid 60 `UpdateFrame` events per second. This is typically called a "fixed timestep".

See [Fix Your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/) for why this is desirable.

See [Quake 3](http://www.funender.com/quake/articles/fps.html) for why you should *not* perform your world updates inside the `RenderFrame` event (short version: in Quake 3, numerical inaccuracies on high fps allow players to jump higher and gain a competitive advantage.)

Edit: for the second part of your question, see [understanding C# events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp). For example:

```
using (var game = new GameWindow())
{
    game.RenderFrame += (sender, e) =>
    {
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
        game.SwapBuffers();
    };
}
```

There is no inherent advantage to subscribing `GameWindow.RenderFrame` compared to inheriting from `GameWindow` and overloading its `OnRenderFrame` method. Pick whichever approach fits your code structure better.

Comment: Thank you for your profound answer. Thirs really helped my understanding as I work with OpenTk for the first time.