# How call the Text_Changed Event for multiple text box controls on a form in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have form that has about 20 `TextBox` controls and I would like to fire the `Text_Changed` event with out adding the event for each individual text box. Is there a way to loop through the text boxes to fire this event? What I am trying to do is clear a label control when the text changes. Instead of displaying a message box, for error descriptions, I use a label control to display the message. I also set it up where if a text box has invalid data, I select all text and give focus to that `TextBox` so when user re-enters information the label control clears the message.

Edit:

To clear up some confusion, here is some of my code from my validation method

```cs
if (txtBentLeadsQty.Text == "")
{
    //ValidData = true;
    BentLeadsCount = 0;
}
else 
{
    if (int.TryParse(txtBentLeadsQty.Text.Trim(), out BentLeadsCount))
        ValidData = true;
    else
    {
        ValidData = false;
        lblError.Text = "Bent Lead Qty must be a numeric value";
        txtBentLeadsQty.SelectAll();
        txtBentLeadsQty.Focus();
    }
}
```

I already have a way to check for numeric values, and I put code in to select all text entered and gave focus if the values are not numeric, I just want to have a way to clear the `Label` control when the the text is changes like if the user hit backspace or starts typing that why if the error occurs, I highlight all the text in that `TextBox` if it is not valid. I can do this if I put code in every text boxes `TextChanged` event, but to save coding I was wondering if there is way to clear the label control if any of the text boxes throws an error from my validation method instead of adding individual events for 20 text boxes.

Note: Not all text boxes will have data entered, these are quantity text boxes I put code in to assign a 0 to the variable if the `TextBox` in null.

Comment: TextChanged is an event. You don't call it. Register same event handler for all your textboxes.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you want to fire the event. It will fire by itself when the user (or other objects in the app) changes Text in any of the text boxes. Then, you want to catch that event and handle it by calling your function which will clear your label. For this, check answers by Nikolay or Kjartan.

Comment: And you don't add events to TextBox. It already has the event. You can register an event handler to each text box's event. This event handler will be the function which will clear your label.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
    {
        if ((ctrl as TextBox) != null)
        {
            (ctrl as TextBox).TextChanged += Form1_TextChanged;
        }
    }
}
private void Form1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show((sender as TextBox).Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to add the same handler to all textboxes in the form dynamically, i.e. without having to add them for each text box in the visual editor (or code).

If so, this might be what you need:

```
// Iterate over all controls in the current form:
foreach (var ctl in Controls)
{
    // Check if the current control is a textbox 
    // (will be null if it is of another type)
    var txtBox = ctl as TextBox;
    if (txtBox != null)
    {
        txtBox.TextChanged += YourMethod();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to programmatically fire the method on each text box.

First, create an array of around 20 text boxes.

```
var textBoxes = new []{textBox0, textBox1, textBox2};
```

Loop through the each box and call the text changed method

```
foreach(var textBox in textBoxes)
{
     TextChangedMethod(textBox);
}
```

If the method you are calling was generated by Visual Studio, it will take a second parameter for EventArgs.  You can simply pass a `null` value for that.

```
TextChangedMethod(textBox, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a method, something like this:

```
public void TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Text-changed code here.
}
```

At this point you can click on each text box on your form and add your new method to the event you want to occur. Click a text box on your form, and click the thunderbolt icon in the properties menu and scroll down to "TextChanged" event. Change that drop down on that event to your new method.

OR

Add the event at run time after you initialize the forms components:

```
textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextChanged);
textBox2.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextChanged);
textBox3.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextChanged);
```

This could be done easier if you add all the text boxes to an array, and loop through them with a foreach to add the event to each one. You could also just grab all the text boxes from the form and loop the same way, though I don't know if you have other controls/text boxes that would make you avoid this method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreach statement.

Example

```
List<TextBox> TextblockCollection = null;//You have to add them all individually to the list
foreach (var text in TextblockCollection)
{
    //Change the text to the same thing, firing the method
    text.Text = text.Text
}
```

Comment: he probably just wants to monitor whether user has changed any of the text boxes

Comment: Oh, it sounded like he wanted to fire the event handler itself without the text being changed by the user.

Comment: to me it sounds like he thinks registering an event handler is "calling the method" for each text box

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes it is an event handler, I will edit my question :)

Comment: I do what want the event to fire when text changes by the user.The text boxes checks for numeric values, if the user enters text, the label controls displays the message and I programmed it to select all text for the text box with invalid data therefore when the user types  a value in that text box, the label control is cleared.

Comment: The event will fire automatically whenever Text in the text boxes is changed by anyone/anything. You only want to handle the event. Now, to validate user input (check if it's text or number) you can use `Int32.TryParse()` or `Float.TryParse()`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to check when any of the text boxes are changed, then check if the new input in the changed textbox is a number (I'm assuming an integer) and then display a message in a label if it's not a number.

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (typeof(control)==typeof(TextBox))
        {
            (control as TextBox).TextChanged += CommonHandler_TextChanged;
        }
    }
}

private void CommonHandler_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number;
    string input=(sender as TextBox).Text;
    bool isnumber=false;
    isnumber = Int32.TryParse(input, number);
    if(isnumber==false)
    {
        yourLabel.Text = "This textbox contains an incorrect number: "
                         +(sender as TextBox).Name;
    }
    else{ /*use the number*/ }
}
```