# c# Double Agent command event handler

Tags: c#, handle, agent

here I'm talking about Double Agent (a windows7/8 version of MS Agent, the same as office 2007 I suppose).

I'm sorry I'm talking about a full product but i'm really being mad to catch an event( the bundled sample does not help for this)...

In the sample i have a similar handle:

```
public MsaWithDa()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    mDaControl = new DoubleAgent.Control.Control ();
    mDaControl.Show += new DoubleAgent.Control.ShowEventHandler (mDaControl_Show);
}
```

and this:

```
private void mDaControl_Show(string CharacterID, DoubleAgent.Control.VisibilityCauseType Cause)
{
    SetDaControlButtons();
}
```

Now I need to handle a different event (when the user select a command from the menu of the Agent).. and I have this

```
private void mainAgent_Command(object sender, AgentObjects.IAgentCtlCommand e) 
{
        mDaControlChar.Play("Wave");
        mDaControlChar.Speak("Hello!");
}
```

It's based on the user manual of the product:

> Double Agent sends this event when your application is input-active
>   and the user chooses a command from the character's pop-up menu, or by
>   spoken input.

```
public event CtlCommandEventHandler CtlCommand
```

I added this to the main form:

```
mDaControl.Command += new DoubleAgent.Control.Command(mDaControl_Command);
```

but something is missing and I have to pass the two values to be able to test.

Sorry, I understand this is a stupid question and sure super-basic but this is the first time I need to use Event Handlers in c#

Hope someone should help, thanks a lot

EDIT:
Based on this article: [Understanding events and event handlers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp)

I now coded this:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, AgentObjects.IAgentCtlCommand e);
public event MyEventHandler AgentObjects;
```

and this:

```
    private void InitializeAgent()
    {
          mDaControl.Command += new MyEventHandler(HandleSomethingHappened);
    }

    private void HandleSomethingHappened(object sender, AgentObjects.IAgentCtlCommand e) 
{
        mDaControlChar.Play("Wave");
        mDaControlChar.Speak("Hello!");
}
```

BUT i have an error here:

```
new MyEventHandler(HandleSomethingHappened)
```

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'XCopyPro.Main.MyEventHandler'
>   to
>   'DoubleAgent.Control.CommandEventHandler' C:\Users\Shawn\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\XCopyPro\XCopyPro\FormMain.cs    159 37  XCopyPro

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a new DoubleAgent.Control.CommandEventHandler instead of a new MyEventHandler.  As long as your method has the same signature as the DoubleAgent event handler it should work.

Comment: This: mDaControl.Command += new DoubleAgent.Control.CommandEventHandler(HandleSomethingHappened); Produce Error 1 No overload for 'HandleSomethingHappened' matches delegate 'DoubleAgent.Control.CommandEventHandler' C:\Users\Shawn\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\XCopyPro\XCopyPro\FormMain.cs 159 37 XCopyPro

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i'm a newbie in C#! You should not help me without docs...

I solved myself following the manual...

The code is pretty simple, somewhere this:

```
mDaControl.Command += new DoubleAgent.Control.CommandEventHandler(mDaControl_Commands);
```

And this:

```
private void mDaControl_Commands(DoubleAgent.Control.UserInput e)
{
    mDaControlChar.Play("Wave");
    mDaControlChar.Speak("Hello!");
}
```