# Grammar issue with respect to anonymous functiosn

Tags: c#

From m$ site. I don't get the += o,a   what is that ???

```
private void GetResponse(Uri uri, Action<Response> callback)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    wc.OpenReadCompleted += (o, a) =>
    {
        if (callback != null)
        {
            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
            callback(ser.ReadObject(a.Result) as Response);
        }
    };
    wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read up on delegates, events, and lambda expressions and that should just about cover it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding events and event handlers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

```
wc.OpenReadCompleted += (o, a) => { }
```

This is assigning an anonymous delegate to the wc.OpenReadCompleted event. The `(o,a)` part are the method parameters.

`o` is object.
`a` is the EventArgs

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the signature of [OpenReadCompletedEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.openreadcompletedeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) (which should be used to subscribe to [OpenReadCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webclient.openreadcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event), `o` is a sender and `a` is an instance of [OpenReadCompletedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.openreadcompletedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

In general this approach of subscription to events is basically instantiating a delegate using a lambda expression, one can do this since C# 3.0.

Comment: But where is the o used/consumed?