# Why does the timer Elapsed need += EventHandler?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I'm following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) to write a Windows Service.
Every 60 seconds, a new event is raised that writes to the event log.
In the code, the new event is raised using the `+=` operator.

```
// Set up a timer that triggers every minute.
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 60000; // 60 seconds
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(this.OnTimer);
timer.Start();
```

Whats the motivation for using this operator here? Why is it not just `=`? Especially the `+` part seems to confuse me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding events and event handlers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

`Elapsed` is an event. From [ECMA-334 C# Language Specification, chapter 15.8.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf#page=340):

> The only operations that are permitted on an event by code that is
>   outside the type in which that event is  declared, are += and -= .

Just assignment `=` would be a syntax error here. And this makes sense, because delegates in C# may have many subscribers. From [ch.20.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-334.pdf#page=403)

> delegate instance encapsulates an invocation list, which is a list of one or more methods

So there are might be several handlers of `Elapsed` event, and `+=` is just an appending another one.