# How to get textbox keypress event?

Tags: c#, events, textbox, keypress

How to copy or duplicate other controls events? I want to use other controls event in a new controls.
Lets say i have a textboxes.

```
TextBox tbTemp = new TextBox ();
tbTemp.Keypress += new KeyPressEventHandler(some keypress); //I assigned some keypress event here & this works fine


TextBox tbNew = new TextBox ();//create new textbox and assign keypress events from existing textbox
tbNew.Keypress += tbTemp.Keypress; //This is not working. It says the event control.keypress can only appear on left hand side of +=

or

tbNew.Keypress += new KeyPressEventHandler(tbTemp.Keypress);//this is not working
```

Is there a way to capture other controls events? I need to capture or duplicate the tbTemp keypressEvent and assigned to new TextBox(tbNew)

Comment: Which keypress events do you exactly wish to capture?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to subscribe single instance of function to KeyPress events of many controls?

Comment: lets say i have a textbox1 which already have a keypress events assigned. What i want is I create new a textbox2, i need to assign textbox2 keypress event from textbox1. Like textbox2.keypress=textbox1 keypress

Comment: `tb1.KeyPress += AFunction; 
tb2.KeyPress += AFunction;` Is this want you want to achieve?

Comment: @LouisGo probably something like that, function that can duplicate some existing controls keypressEvent

Comment: Your wording is confusing. If you want 4 controls fire event and run the same function. Just subscribe it for times, like my previous comment. Please edit you question and elaborate on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I post this answer if your question is

> "I have many textboxes, but if any of one "KeyPress" are fires, I want the same function handle it."

All you need to do is subscribe the same function `OnKeyPress` to different controls' events.

```
// This is the function
private void OnKeyPress( object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e )
{
    // Your implementation.
}


// Your constructor or where your subscribe event.
void Constructor()
{
 // This will work
    tbTemp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(OnKeyPress);

    tbNew += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(OnKeyPress);
}
```

If this is not answering your question, please edit and explain what you want to achieve.

========

Your question was

> I need to capture or duplicate the tbTemp keypressEvent and assigned to new TextBox(tbNew)

Each control has its own `KeyPress` event, you don't have to copy ( duplicate ) it. So "duplicate KeyPress event" is confusing.

Then I assume you do not want to "duplicate event" but "subscribe same event of controls to a single function."

Take a look at [Understanding events and event handlers in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803242/understanding-events-and-event-handlers-in-c-sharp)

It should help for explain your question.